# Indexing Faces with AWS Rekognition

Tags: amazon-web-services, indexing, collections, face-recognition

I am new to AWS and am trying to use Rekognition to identify certain people in a crowd. I am currently trying to index the images of the separate individuals but have hit a snag when trying to create a collection. There seems to a data type compatibility issue when I try using Amazon.Rekognition.Model.S3Object(). I have provided the code below. Does anyone have a solution or a better method? Thank you for your time!

```
    private static void TryIndexFaces()
    {
        S3Client = new AmazonS3Client();
        RekognitionClient = new AmazonRekognitionClient();

        IndexFacesRequest indexRequest = new IndexFacesRequest();
        Amazon.Rekognition.Model.Image img = new Amazon.Rekognition.Model.Image();

        ListObjectsV2Request req = new ListObjectsV2Request();
        req.BucketName = "wem0020";
        ListObjectsV2Response listObjectsResponse = S3Client.ListObjectsV2(req);


        CreateCollectionRequest ccr = new CreateCollectionRequest();
        ccr.CollectionId = "TestFaces";
        //RekognitionClient.CreateCollection(ccr);

        ListVersionsResponse lvr = S3Client.ListVersions(req.BucketName);
        string version = lvr.Versions[0].VersionId;

        foreach(Amazon.S3.Model.S3Object s3o in listObjectsResponse.S3Objects)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s3o.Key);
            try
            {
                if (s3o.Key.EndsWith(".jpg"))
                {
                    Amazon.Rekognition.Model.S3Object reks3o = new Amazon.Rekognition.Model.S3Object();
                    reks3o.Bucket = req.BucketName;
                    reks3o.Name = s3o.Key;
                    Console.WriteLine(version);
                    reks3o.Version = version;
                    img.S3Object = reks3o;

                    indexRequest.Image = img;
                    indexRequest.CollectionId = ccr.CollectionId;

                    RekognitionClient.IndexFaces(indexRequest);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To index faces, use the bounding boxes value returned from aws rekognition. I have done with python

```
 widtho = 717 #width of the given image
 heighto = 562 #height of the given image
 counter = 0
 facecount = 1
 s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
 bucket = s3.Bucket('rek')
 if __name__ == "__main__":
 #Choosing the file in s3 bucket
     photo = 'sl.jpg'
     bucket = 'rek'
 #Intilization of rekognition and performing detect_faces 
 client = boto3.client('rekognition', region_name='eu-west-1')
 response = client.detect_faces(
 Image={'S3Object': {'Bucket': bucket, 'Name': photo}}, Attributes=['ALL'])
 print('Detected faces for ' + photo)
 print('The faces are detected and labled from left to right')
 for faceDetail in response['FaceDetails']:
     print('Face Detected= ', i)
     #To mark a bounding box of the image using coordinates
     print('Bounding Box')
     bboxlen = len(faceDetail['BoundingBox'])
     print(bboxlen)
     width = faceDetail['BoundingBox'].get('Width')
     height = faceDetail['BoundingBox'].get('Height')
     left = faceDetail['BoundingBox'].get('Left')
     top = faceDetail['BoundingBox'].get('Top')
     w = int(width * widtho)
     h = int(height * heighto)
     x = int(left * widtho)
     y = int(top * heighto)
     cv2.rectangle(imagere, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
```

this loop will index faces one by one in the single frame